# PowerShell Remove-Item cannot delete populated folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete some files in:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\

Under `my_site`, there are many files and folders, including bin folders which has some .dll files. As soon as I run the script, I get an error message that some of the .dll files cannot be accessed because they are being used by another process, and on some dlls, I get a permission denied error.

I don't know what the problem is.  I am using the following script, which works perfect for any other folders, but not for the one I am trying to delete.

```
get-childitem "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\" -recurse | % {

remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force

}
```

Comment: you're getting a legitimate error message... [maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225802/how-to-determine-which-process-is-holding-a-file-in-windows).

Comment: strange thing is if i go into that folder and select all and delete them , it deletes everything but using script i get error i dont know why

Comment: is your script in my_site?

Comment: you should take out the `-recurse` parameter on `Remove-Item`, because you cannot recursively delete one file. Although I don't imagine that would be causing your error

Comment: my script is in a different folder. basically i am trying to restore a website from a recent backup. and to restore the backup i first need to delete the content in my_site and than replace it with the backup

Comment: What is the working directory you are executing from? If it's within the folder you're trying to delete, you'll have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell as Administrator

The C:\inetpub directory has special permissions that require you to run it as an administrator in order to make any changes inside the folder.

Comment: I am running powershell as an admin. but still no luck. strange thing is if i issue normal remove -item command from powershell window it deletes the admin content but same stuff if i write within a script it gives me error message

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I am using

```
   $content = get-childitem 'C:\Backups\my_site'      
   $sortedContent = $content |  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending  


   write-host "This is the list of all the backups for my_site :"

   $count = 1
   foreach ($item in $sortedContent)
   {

    Write-Host ("{0}: {1}" -f $count, $item.Name)
    $count++ 
    }



    # 2.Take input from user
    $itemNumber = Read-Host "Please select which backup you want to restore"
    $confirmation = Read-Host "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"
    # 2.Take input from user

    if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {

    # 3. BACKUP script
   ./bacup_mysite.ps1
    # 3. BACKUP 

    # 4. DELETE CONTENTS OF my_site


    get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\" -recurse | % {

    remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force

    }

    }


    # 4. DELETE CONTENTS OF APP

    # 5. COPY CONTENTS OF ZIP INTO APP DIRECTORY
    $itemNumber = $itemNumber -1
    if($sortedContent[$itemNumber].PSIsContainer -eq $true)
    { 
    $src = $sortedContent[$itemNumber].FullName + "\"


    $WebzipPath = $src + "my_site.zip"


    $Date = Get-Date
    $folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")
    $tempPath = 'C:\_Temp\Restore\my_site_restore_' + $folder_date
    if (!(Test-Path -path $tempPath)) 
    {
        New-Item $tempPath -type directory
    }   


    ./Library/unzip.ps1 $WebzipPath $tempPath



    $tempPathWeb = $tempPath + "/my_site/*" 

    Copy-Item  -Path $tempPat -Destination 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\' -Recurse -
    force
```